# What is the Exception class to use in rescue_from to catch 422 errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display a custom 422 page in my application. What is the Exception class I am supposed to catch in the `rescue_from` declaration?

This how I handle the RecordNotFound exceptions:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,  :with => :render_404
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is a list that maps the exception class with appropriate status code. You go through this [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController/Rescue). In your case, there are three: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved, and ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.